# Python, write a new line in a CSV-File

Tags: python, csv, line

I'm working on a Python-Script which takes some
weather information from a Website and put it in a CSV-File every day.

I want to append the new information below and not directly behind it.

This is my CSV-Append-Function:

```
def save_data(weatherdatasaved):
filename = "weather.csv"
header="Datum;Luft-Min;Luft-Max;Durchschn.Wassertemp;Barometer"+"\n"
#Check whether the file exists
if(os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser(filename))==False):
    file = open(os.path.expanduser(filename),"wb")
    file.write(bytes(header, encoding="ascii",errors="ignore"))
    file.close()

file = open(os.path.expanduser(filename),"a")
i=0
while (i < len(weatherdatasaved)):
    if((i+1)==len(weatherdatasaved):
       file.write(weatherdatasaved[i]+"\n")
    else:
        file.write(weatherdatasaved[i]+";")
    i+=1
file.close()
```

What I Get:

```
Datum;Luft-Min;Luft-Max;Durchschn.Wassertemp;Barometer01.11.2016;9.5;6.8;12;1023.2
```

What I want:

```
Max;Durchschn.Wassertemp;Barometer

01.11.2016;9.5;6.8;12;1023.2
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: As a CSV shouldn't you have this as comma separated rather than semi-colon separated?

Comment: @ugano unfortunately there is no agreement on how CSV files are formatted. So you're free to use whatever you like.
@derMatt Are you on windows or linux? I suspect your lines *do* end with `\n` but your editor doesn't break the line when looking at the file.

Comment: I am not too familiar with the `bytes` class, but I suspect that the problem is in that line. can you try just to write the header without any additional arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to work with different OS, you can use the os.linebreak attribute. 
For example:

```
import os

multiline = 'line 1' + os.linesep + 'line 2'
```

In your case replace all `\n` with `os.linesep`.

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "\r\n" in place of "\n"